# saving values from input created entry boxes in Tkinter

Tags: tkinter, python-3.6

So I'm pretty new to Tkinter, but I did some looking and I found no information on this.  What I want to do specifically is to create a button that makes entry boxes, and then save those entry boxes into some sort of variable.  I can't seem to find a way to link new widgets to a variable when I create them via a button or other user input. For example:

```
def new_category(self):
    print (rownum)
    new = Toplevel()
    new.title("New System")
    add_ablilty = Button(new, text="Add Ablity", command=lambda: self.new_entry(new))
    add_ablilty.pack()

def new_entry(self, window):
    Entry(window).pack()
```

Comment: I would use a list to store the entry fields instead of a variable name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code will assign `StringVar` instances to each `Entry`, then print them every time you add a new entry, by adding them to a list.

```
def new_category(self):
    new = Toplevel()
    new.title("New System")
    vals=[]
    self.varlists.append(vals)
    index=len(self.varlists)-1
    add_ablilty = Button(new, text="Add Ablity", command=lambda: self.new_entry(new, index))
    add_ablilty.pack()
def new_entry(self, window, index):
    print(list((i.get()) for i in self.varlists[index]))
    var=StringVar()
    self.varlists[index].append(var)
    Entry(window, textvariable=var).pack()
```

Add the following line to the `__init__` function of whatever class this is:

```
self.varlists=[]
```